# How to get matrix out of cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array A that is 1x1. It contains either a vector of matrix of doubles. How do I get that matrix out of the cell array?

For example, something along the lines of:
     matrix = A(1);

And then I can perform normal vector/matrix operations.

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, it is easy! Use brackets.

```
matrix_A1 = A{1};
```

For a cell array `A`, the usual parenthesis `A(1)` returns a cell array. `A{1}` returns the contents of the cell.